# undefine AutoCAD commands using .NET

Tags: c#, autocad

I am looking for a way to customize the AutoCAD move command. I have tried the code in the link below without sucess. I received no errors executing it, it just ran the normal AutoCAD open command.

http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2007/03/replacing_the_o.html

I also tried this link with no positive results either.

http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/disable-certain-commands-for-a-given-entity-or-a-class-in-net.html

The question posted here titled "Override/Customize AutoCAD Command" suggested using overrules. I am not convinced that this is the right approach either. I am certain that I'm missing something and cannot find sufficient information to determine just what it is. A link to it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what kind of customization you want/need for the MOVE command? Indeed the overrule will alter the transformBy behavior, but you can replace the command by UNDEFINE (but the user can still call the native command)

Comment: I want to customize the move command to execute other tasks along with the move command. I have tried using the UNDEFINE code from the first link above unsucessfully. Even using that code as is did not perform as advertised.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest your check the CommandEnded event, then **after** MOVE you perform your code. You cannot perform tasks during the MOVE built-in command and, honestly, replace it with your own can be a big work...

Comment: Why not simply customize the commands by the alias editor ? Every ACAD command can be redefined. And if nothing helps write some code which hooks in the autocad events. There is a event which is triggered before the command is excecuted...